# how to implement Snapchat's custom pull to refresh in pure flutter

Tags: flutter, swiperefreshlayout, pull-to-refresh

how to implement Snapchat's custom pull to refresh with no packages ? if there is no way to do it without them then suggest me ones

demo :  https://i.stack.imgur.com/0KbuB.gif

Comment: https://pub.dev/packages/custom_refresh_indicator

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ORApMlzwMdM